# Upload the more than one files in the same directory on aws s3 using ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-1.9

I have three files as

```
1_timestamp.mp4, 
2_timestamp.mp4,
3_timestamp.mp4
```

By combining these files I am creating **combined_timestamp.mp4** file, after that I am uploading combined_timestamp.mp4 file to aws s3.Upload functionality works fine.

But now I have to upload 1_timestamp.mp4, 2_timestamp.mp4, 3_timestamp.mp4 files along with combined_timestamp.mp4.

Is this possible to upload all these files under one **timestamp folder**. So that I can group them under one folder.

If it is possible, them please guide me.

I am using **ruby 1.9.3**, **fog** and **gem "aws-sdk", ">= 1.8.1.2"**

Comment: How are you uploading the files? Through Paperclip or directly?

Comment: Files are uploading directly because my app is totally built in only ruby and not in rails.

Comment: Okay! I only know about Paperclip right now sorry :(

Comment: @RichPeck, one quick question, is this possible to upload them in same folder?

Comment: @RichPeck one thing I alos used `gem fog`

Comment: I think you should be able to, yes. You'll have to define the folder before-hand though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141499/1120015):

> There is no concept of folders or directories in S3. You can create
>   file names like "abc/xys/uvw/123.jpg", which many S3 access tools like
>   S3Fox show like a directory structure, but it's actually just a single
>   file in a bucket.