# list all the files from s3 using aws-sdk gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-1.9.3

I have a following scenario.
Consider in my case **aws s3 folder structure** is as follows

```
- videos
  - my_videos
    - college
```

I have uploaded video file say `myfirst_day.mp4` in the `college`, for this related formed key is `"videos/my_videos/college/myfirst_day.mp4"`

Now I have to list all the files from the `videos/my_videos/college` directory.
How can I do it.

For this I am using **aws-sdk gem**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simple iterate over `bucket` `objects` and use the `with_prefix` method

```
s3.buckets[YOUR BUCKET NAME].objects.with_prefix('videos/my_videos/college').each.collect(&:key)
#=> ["videos/my_videos/college/myfirst_day.mp4"]
```

OR use the `as_tree` method

```
s3.buckets[YOUR BUCKET NAME].as_tree(prefix:'videos/my_videos/college').select(&:leaf?).collect(&:key)
 #=> ['videos/my_videos/college/myfirst_day.mp4']
```

Obviously these are fictional since I have no access to your bucket but take a look at `ObjectCollection` and `Tree` for more methods in the [AWSSDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html).

There are quite a few methods for bucket traversal available such as `Tree` responds to `children` which will list both `LeafNode`s (File) and `BranchNode`s (Directory). `BranchNode`s will then also respond to `children` so you can make this recursive if needed.

To get the `suffix` (e.g. just the filename) you could possibly patch these in.

```
class LeafNode
  def suffix
    @member.key.split(delimiter).pop
  end
end
class S3Object
  def suffix
    @key.split("/").pop
  end
end
```

I have not fully tested these in any way but they should work for returning just the file name itself if it is nested inside a branch.

Comment: I am doing the same thing. Is there any way of just getting the filename, and not the entire path?

Comment: @theTuxRacer there is a `prefix` method but I don't see a `suffix` method although this would be an easy patch i have updated my answer for clarification

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Thats what I ended up doing in the end :)

Comment: @theTuxRacer no problem. Glad it's working for you seems like this should be part of the gem as I am sure your not the only user that would like this functionality.

Comment: Hi @engineersmnky I looked at this answer which explains why we get the OP as we do. It was the first time I read of it, and posting it here, assuming that you do not know either: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20012200/174936 Apologies if it is not the case. Thank you.

Comment: @theTuxRacer not sure I understand the comment? `list_objects` responds as a `Core::Response` in `XML` Format so yes you could technically use this although implementation seems a bit more complex