# Iterate over files in a directory in pySpark to automate dataframe and SQL table creation

Tags: apache-spark, automation, pyspark

So, the basics are:

- I'm on Spark 2.+
- I'm running this all in a Jupyter notebook
- My goal is to iterate over a number of files in a directory and have spark (1) create dataframes and (2) turn those dataframes into sparkSQL tables. Basically, I want to be able to open the notebook at anytime and have a clean way of always loading everything available to me.

Below are my imports:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

fileDirectory = 'data/'
```

Below is the actual code:

```
for fname in os.listdir(fileDirectory):
    sqlContext.read.format("csv").\
            option("header", "true").\
            option("inferSchema", "true").\
            load(fname)

    df_app = app_dat_df
    df_app.createOrReplaceTempView(fname)
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
AnalysisException: u'Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.;'
```

It would appear that it's not finding issue with the way I'm passing over the files (great), but it's not letting me infer schemas. When I manually go over each file, this has never been an issue.

Can someone give me some pointers on where I can improve them/get it to run?

Many, many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the path is right ?  That you want to access the local file system and that your working directory is `data/`? `fname` is just the name of the file not the full path to it. If the problem comes from a file you should add a print to your loop to see which one is the problem

Comment: Good point. I forgot to mention that, but yes, the path and all of that is correct. If I run the following code, file by file, it works fine: 

`df_name = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")\
.load("data/file_name.csv")`

`df = df_name`

`df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_name")`

Comment: so your working directory is not data it's the parent directory of data. In your code you're accessing `transaction_dat.csv` directly. Try `fileDirectory + fname` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `inferSchema` is throwing error you should manually specify the schema of your csv data.

Also as @Marie has mentioned you would need to slightly modify your load syntax.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

customSchema = StructType([
    StructField("string_col", StringType(), True),
    StructField("integer_col", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("double_col", DoubleType(), True)])

fileDirectory = 'data/'
for fname in os.listdir(fileDirectory):
    df_app = sqlContext.read.format("csv").\
        option("header", "true"). \
        schema(customSchema). \
        load(fileDirectory + fname)
```

Hope this helps!

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: How can this be replicated if the file directory is a S3 bucket? Will be glad if there is a similar implementation..

Comment: @SubhankarNayak you may want to look here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803027/retrieving-subfolders-names-in-s3-bucket-from-boto3