# How to get CommonPrefixes w/o usage of low-level Client in boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39009774/258483) one can retrieve immediate "subdirectories" by querying by prefix and then obtaining `CommonPrefix` of the result of [`Client.list_objects()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) method.

Unfortunately, `Client` is a part of so-called "low level" API.

I am using different API:

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                  aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
result = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)
```

and [this method does not return dictionary](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects).

Is it possible to obtain common prefixes with higher level API in boto3?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372405/758174), it seems that the `Resource` doesn't handle `Delimiter` well.  It is often annoying, when your entire stack relies on `Resource`, to be told that, ah, you should have instantiated a `Client` instead...

Fortunately, a `Resource` object, such as your `Bucket` above, contains a `client` as well.

So, instead of the last line in your code sample, do:

```
paginator = my_bucket.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects')
for resp in paginator.paginate(Bucket=my_bucket.name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/', ...):
    for x in resp.get('CommonPrefixes', []):
        print(x['Prefix'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access `client` from `session`.

```
session.client('s3').list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix= prefix)
```