# listing s3 buckets using boto3 and python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-glue

I am using the below code and referred to many [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803027/retrieving-subfolders-names-in-s3-bucket-from-boto3) answers for listing files under a folder using `boto3` and `python` but was unable to do so. Below is my code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        object_listing = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='maxValue',
                                    Prefix='madl-temp/')
```

My s3 path is `"s3://madl-temp/maxValue/`" where I want to find if there are any parquet files under the maxValue bucket based on which I have to do something like below:

```
If len(maxValue)>0:
 maxValue=true
else:
 maxValue=false
```

I am running it via `Glue` jobs and I am getting the below error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

Comment: I want to ensure that it returns 0 if I try to print the size of 'contents' and if it contains the n objects then it should return n as the value but in your case it is returning 1 as the value even though there are no objects in that bucket

Comment: Then do `len(object_listing['Contents']) - 1`. The empty folder `maxValue/` is considered as 1. So you will always have one more value (all files + one folder).

Comment: Okay is it the right way of doing it? Any documentation reference?

Comment: You can just `print(object_listing['Contents'])` and you will see that there will be the folder name included, even though there is no files.

Comment: This happens because in S3 there are no folders nor files. Everything is an object. So your `madl-temp/` is also an object, just like `madl-temp/file.parquet` "file".

Comment: Okay understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bucket name is `madl-temp` and prefix is `maxValue`. But in boto3, you have the opposite. So it should be:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
object_listing = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='madl-temp',
                                    Prefix='maxValue/')
```

To get the number of files you have to do:

```
len(object_listing['Contents']) - 1
```

where `-1` accounts for a prefix `maxValue/`.

Comment: It worked but when I am trying to find the `len` of `object_listing` it is returning the length of the prefix i.e 8. But I want 0 since there are no files under `maxValue`

Comment: @Debuggerrr The proper where to check it is `len(object_listing['Contents'])`.

Comment: Cool but still it is giving `1` as the value but there are no files under `maxValue`. Why is it so?

Comment: @Debuggerrr You have to provide full output of `object_listing`. I don't know what it is, and your question does not provide such information either.

Comment: In the post, I have mentioned that `"to check whether there are any parquet files are not"` and even if I try to display `object_listing['Contents']` it is still giving me `1`. How do I print the value?

Comment: Try `print(object_listing)` and see what it returns to you.

Comment: not sure if it's default behavior but sometimes the prefix itself is returned. I usually look for it the list and remove it. You may also want to add Delimiter='/' argument and see if that changes the response

Comment: okay I can try adding delimiter option