# Download all files in S3 bucket with any given number of subfolder levels with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I know there threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918960/boto3-to-download-all-files-from-a-s3-bucket) that shows how to use `Boto3` to download all files: either in a bucket, or a folder (i.e. `key`) directly under the bucket.

What would be a generic solution to download all files in a subfolder of any number of levels, as long as the S3 path is given. For example:

```
s3://bucket_name/level_1_folder/level_2_folder/.../level_N_folder/
```

Comment: The answer you link to will download all items under `level_1_folder/level_2_folder/` if you pass that in for the `dist` value.  If that's not what you mean, can you elaborate on what you expect to happen if you pass in that path, or what you would like to pass into the function?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372405/758174) helps? (Disclaimer -- that's my answer; there are others on that page you may want to look at).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site for asking somebody to write code for you. Can you show us what you have tried so far? Do you have a _specific_ problem you are wanting to solve?