# Lookup Key from S3 Bucket using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I've taken a [script](https://github.com/pauld-splunk/aws-splunk-firehose-error-reingest/blob/main/firehose-reingest/lambda_function.py) written by Paul Davies about reingesting Splunk Logs from the AWS Cloud.

The

When my logs have failed to process in Kinesis Firehose they get placed in a backup S3 bucket. The Current format of the key is the following:

```
Folder/Folder/Year/Month/Day/HH/failedlogs
```

Example:

```
splunk-kinesis-firehose/splunk-failed/2023/01/01/01/failedlogs.gz
```

The key lookup in the script is set like this

```
key=urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
```

Is there way to get all the files within the following S3 Bucket under the sub folder - splunk-kinesis-firehose or is there a better way of looping through all folders?

Comment: It appears that you are using an AWS Lambda function, which is being triggered by the creation of a log file -- is this correct? If so, the name ('Key') of the object is passed through the `event` record as shown in your Question, with the expectation that the Lambda function should only operate on that one specific object. If you want to list the objects in a bucket you should call [`list_objects_v2()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html), passing the full path to the folder in the `Prefix` parameter.

Comment: That is correct although the way Paul D has set this up, is to trigger the Lambda when S3 Bucket Event has happened aka a file has been placed in this bucket. In my situation I will trigger the Lambda manually but I want to understand how I can grab all the files within that S3 Bucket.

Answer (score 1):

As John Rotenshtein says, your Lambda function, if invoked by S3 trigger, will receive the key as part of the request. You could also invoke the Lambda manually and pass the key in the request.

But if, for some reason, you want to do a full (or partial) listing under a path, then please take a look at `s3list()` that I describe in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372405/758174). It is a fairly general S3 lister. In your case, you would call it with:

```py
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('bucket-name')
path = 'splunk-kinesis-firehose/splunk-failed'

for s3obj in s3list(bucket, path, list_dirs=False):
    key = s3obj.key
    ...
```

to get *all* the objects under that path, or, for example:

```py
for s3obj in s3list(bucket, path, start='2023/05/01', end='2023/06', list_dirs=False):
    key = s3obj.key
    ...
```

to get just the files for the month of May 2023.

Note that `s3list` is a `generator`: you can start listing a trillion objects and stop whenever you like (internally, it goes by chunks of upo to 1000 objects per call to AWS).

Answer (score 0):

To list objects in an Amazon S3 bucket you can use the **client method:** [list_objects_v2 - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html):

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='your-bucket-name',
    Prefix='splunk-kinesis-firehose',
)
```

Or you can use the **resource method**, which is a bit more Pythonic:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('your-bucket-name')

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```