# How to create a new folder in S3 using AWS PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I have a bucket already created but I want to create new folders inside this bucket, not upload data or anything else, just create new folders. How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon S3 boto - how to create a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939743/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-create-a-folder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS S3 doesn't really have a first class concept of a "folder" or "directory". S3 objects have prefixes, which are segmented by slashes, so there is certainly the appearance of folders, but it is not possible to have a truly empty directory structure.

However, their AWS Console user experience does present content as such, and provides a button to "Create Folder". When using that button, the UI provides the below message:

> When you create a folder, S3 console creates an object with the above
>   name appended by suffix "/" and that object is displayed as a folder
>   in the S3 console.

You could try using PowerShell's Put Object API/cmdlet to create empty objects named per that instruction. For example, you could create a folder named "my-new-folder" by creating an object named "my-new-folder/".

Comment: Thanks David, I fixed using New-S3Object with the entire "path" in the bucket name

Answer (score 2):

S3 is object storage; it's  not a regular file system. Generally speaking, there is no need to attempt to create folders. Simply upload objects, for example teams/east/falcons/logo.png.

If you really, really want to give the impression that there are folders then you can create zero-sized objects whose names ends in / (or whatever your preferred folder delimiter is). The simplest way to do this is with the AWS S3 console but any SDK will let you do it too (simply issue a PutObject with no body).

Answer (score 0):

I was seaching for this myself and found [this](https://tommymaynard.com/aws-write-s3object-folder-creation-problem-2018/).

use `-content where content = key then -file or -folder are not needed`

```
$s3Path = "/folder/" + 'subfolder/'
Write-S3Object -BucketName $s3Bucket -Key $s3Path -Content $s3Path
```