# Create directory of username in s3 from django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to create directory on S3 using the name fetched from Django SQL database. I was trying to do this but it shows `{}` as the S3 bucket name. How should I resolve this?

Comment: Do you want to only create folders ? Or you will also populate it with data sometime ?

Comment: want  to create folders privately

Answer (score 0):

`There is no concept of folders or directories in S3. Management console just present it like that. In Amazon S3, we only have buckets and objects.`

Still if we want to create folders, we can create any object like "abc/xyz/uvw/123.jpg", which many S3 access tools like S3 Management Console, S3Fox show like a directory structure, but it's actually just a single file in a bucket. Refer https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Reference & Credit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141499/5647272