# Adding timestamp to your amazon s3 bucket folder names

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to add system time as timestamp to my s3 bucket folder names so that every time i run the code, it would create a separate folder with a different time stamp on s3.
 How do i achieve this ?

```
import json
import boto3    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3object = s3.Object('your-bucket-name', 'your_file.json')

s3object.put(
    Body=(bytes(json.dumps(json_data).encode('UTF-8')))
)
```

Comment: Trying to automate hourly pull of data and storing it in s3 folders, separated by different time stamps. Data pulled at 2pm, goes to folder_2pm. Data pulled at 3 pm goes to folder_3pm.

Comment: The timestamps will be prefixes for the key names of the object you put to the s3 bucket.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939743/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-create-a-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [standard Python date functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to construct the folder name you want, then set that string as part of the S3 object's key. Something like this:

```
import json
import boto3    
from datetime import datetime

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
prefix = 'folder_' + datetime.now().strftime("%I%p") + "/"
s3object = s3.Object('your-bucket-name', prefix + 'your_file.json')

s3object.put(
    Body=(bytes(json.dumps(json_data).encode('UTF-8')))
)
```